# find the row where dates overlap Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have  two sets of date ranges and have used sumproduct to  identify which date ranges in the first 2 columns overlap with any of the  date ranges in the second two columns

what I need now is   to identify which row the overlap in the second date ranges occurs
so as you can see below

```
TK  30/03/2015  24/04/2015  22/12/2014  21/01/2015      TRUE
TK  20/04/2015  24/04/2015  19/05/2015  21/01/2015      FALSE
TK  27/04/2015  15/05/2015  22/04/2015  04/04/2015      TRUE
TK  18/05/2015  20/05/2015  05/02/2015  09/02/2015      FALSE
TK  21/05/2015  22/05/2015  10/02/2015  11/02/2015      FALSE
TK  25/05/2015  25/05/2015  12/02/2015  12/02/2015      FALSE
```

The formula used in G is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$5)* ((B2<=$E$2:$E$5)* (C2>=$D$2:$D$5)+ (D2<=$C$2:$C$5)* (E2>=$B$2:$B$5)))>0
```

The columns used are A- G
As  you can see Row 3 Dates overlap with row 1 dates

What I need to do is get the row numbers for the overlap dates  this is eluding me  I wonder if  anyone could help

regards

JM

Hello again

hit a snag

## N/A appears when I  expand the Range area

any ideas what  I am doing wrong

thanks again  Jo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make this an *all-in-one* formula, add a `ROW(...)` function directly into your `SUMPRODUCT`.

[image: Which row]

The formula in G2 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($2:$7)*(A2=$A$2:$A$7)*((B2<=$E$2:$E$7)*(C2>=$D$2:$D$7)+(D2<=$C$2:$C$7)*(E2>=$B$2:$B$7)))
```

That will show the actual row on the worksheet. If you prefer to indicate the *row within* the data block, substitute `ROW($1:$6)` for `ROW($2:$7)`.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped worked exactly as I had hoped  for.  I can now use it  to  glean associated  information  Thanks and well done.

Comment: All was well until I tried to expand the  Range  Now #N/a is returned.   In total I am only  checking 350  rows   but it errors at 7 so  I am puzzled.  Could you help or  should I post the question again

Comment: You will have to edit your post so I can see how you've changed the cell ranges. Without seeing what was done, anything I offer would be a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the below around your formula, it will return the row number whenever it currently returns TRUE

=IF(forumla=TRUE,ROW(A2),0)

your column G should now look like this

2
0
4
0
0
0

I hope this helps

Erik

Comment: I'll keep your method  in abeyance as I  may need a  full list of rows but in this instance Jeeped provided the solution.  Never the less  the option is well worth noting.  Many Thanks